# _why_ does AoT drop this value?

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 project with environment variables .. I have been using a common.ts file in the environment/ folder like this:

#### environment.prod.ts

```
import common from './common/common';

export const environment: any = {
  ... common,

  production: true,
  devEnvironment: false,
  ...
```

building with `--prod` causes the values in common to be undefined (this is **very** apparent as the *environment.startupProject* property that comes from *common* defines the default route in app routing), but we're finding that odd since we can see the Object.assign in the compiled javascript and it *has* the values there:

#### somewhere deep in main...ts

```
    kZql: function(t, e, n) {
        "use strict";
        n.d(e, "a", function() {
            return r
        });
        var r = (this && this.__assign || Object.assign || function(t) {
            for (var e, n = 1, r = arguments.length; n < r; n++)
                for (var i in e = arguments[n])
                    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, i) && (t[i] = e[i]);
            return t
        }
        )({}, {
            projectName: "accounts",
            startupProject: "/dashboard",
...
        }, {
            production: !0,
            devEnvironment: !1,
...
        })
    },
```

Note that this is true even though sourcemaps are turned off..

---

update: if I modify main.ts to console.log that same common:

```
import common from '@src/environments/common/common';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  console.log(common);
}
```

it is defined! it is only from the context of environment.prod itself that it is not defined.

---

If I use the debugger and *turn on sourcemaps* then set the breakpoint at the initialization of environment object in environment.prod, I can see that common (or rather, it's underlying uglified variable) is in fact undefined. So I guess that snippet just above, that is not actually executing..at least not before environment is being accessed in our routes module. There's apparently another copy of the same code also being generated, somewhere, and it is running that one. which makes me thing AoT is not doing a very good job, frankly.

it's almost like there is a left-over bit of tree-shaking that is actually embedded into our project, and behaves differently that the tree-shaking that goes on during compilation.

Why does this happen?

Worse, I can't fix it in any of the usual ways:

avoiding export default does nothing.

converting it to a class and adding to app-module does not work!:

```
@Injectable()
export class Common {
  static startupProject = '/dashboard';
}

//... and in app.module
...
providers: [
  Common,
...

//... then in environment.prod:
import { Common as common } from ...

export environment: any = {
  ...common, // this works without --prod, of course, but not with it
}
```

both of the above, combined with migrating the folder `common/` to be under `app/` also does not work.

Avoiding the *splat* operator like `Object.assign({}, common, {/* ...env ...*/})`... that too does not work.

assigning the value to `(window as any).common` does not work (this has been prescribed as a way to prevent tree-shaking in answers in the angular repo). In fact, that still doesn't work even if I also use `...(window as any).common,` instead of the imported copy in the environment!

Is there any way outside of turning off AoT to get this to work so we dont have to keep duplicate copies of information? What is really going on -- why does the file exist in the compiled JS output but still it is undefined during runtime?

Comment: What's the difference between the `environment.prod.ts` and `environment.ts` in regards to the `common`?

Comment: in regards to common? nothing. they are identical in the first couple of lines. the reason we have a common file is that rather than setting the same variables in each, we want to avoid duplication and just set them once

Answer (score 1):

if you look through the angular.json you will find such piece of configuration

```
"fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
```

witch throws away your environment.ts and builds your app with environment.prod.ts instead. to fix your issue i guess you need just to remove "fileReplacements" section from the configuration

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. this is in the environment.prod.ts file. But note that the second snippet in my post has always been clearly showing the contents of common.ts are being merged with the contents of the environment file at that location in the compiled code, so I dont know why you thoguht this would be the answer.

Comment: could you check whether it is aot or terser optimization, that is breaking your config? try ng serve --aot; or ng serve --prod --optimization=false and ng serve --prod --aot=false

Comment: sure, this is a good idea :) `ng serve --aot` produces the same error (also when combined with `--optimization=false`).  So too, `ng serve --prod --aot=false` continues to exhibit the same behavior... I'm not sure that the "false" toggles work the way you are hoping. `ng serve --env=prod --optimization=true` works. I just have to note that aot is triggering the problem, but it is not stripping the common file from the compiled code, as can be seen in the snippet in my post.

Comment: I think it was just a typo on my part regarding: `ng serve --prod --aot=false ` .. I've just redone it and it is working, the rest remain as reported